# Does creating a wrapper library infringe copyright?

Tags: copyright, software

I am thinking about writing a [wrapper library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) for a proprietary library.

Due to the nature of a wrapper library, its API would be very similar to the API of the original library in terms of what functions and classes it would provide and how they would be used. However, there would be differences (added functions, changed parameters, etc.) and the names of the functions and classes would be different.

Would that infringe copyright law?

I live in Germany and the company developing the proprietary library is located in the US.

Comment: I do not understand the fact pattern or question personally due to my lack of programming knowledge, even though I have a good command of copyright law generally, but it appears that someone more knowledgable about programming at LawSE might be able to provide an answer to this question, so I am not asking to close the question.